# AngularJS filter based on array of strings?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-show

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around how to go about doing an Angular filter to solve a problem that I'm running into.

Here's a basic example of my data structure, an array of tasks:

```
var tasks = [
    { Title: "This is a task title",
      Tags: ["Test","Tag","One","Two","Three"] },
    { Title: "Another test tag title",
      Tags: ["Some", "More", "Tags"] },
    { Title: "One more, why not",
      Tags: ["I","Like","Dirt"] },
    { Title: "Last one!",
      Tags: ["You","Like","Dirt"] }
];
```

So each object has an array of tags. For the sake of example let's say I am outputting each of those objects as a row in a table.

Once the pages ng-controller is initialized, I'm **grabbing all of the tags from all of the tasks** (without duplicates) and assembling them into a `tags` array.

Then, I'm outputting those tags as toggle-able buttons on the page. All the buttons are blue by default, meaning "active" (in other words: show tasks with this tag contained therein). I need to be able to click on one of those buttons to "toggle off" that tag -- which will filter out any tasks rows in the table wherein the task has that tag.

Like so for visual reference -- grey = "hide tasks whose tags contains this tag", blue = "show tasks whose tags contain this tag":

[image: So you'd see a big row of buttons like this].

Clicking on a button turns it grey, filtering out any tasks in the table that have that tag. I can then click the buttons again to toggle that tag back on, re-showing all tasks with that tag.

Am I explaining this clearly enough? It's a confusing system.

Anyway, I've tried the following:

`ng-filter="task in filteredWithTags = (tasks | filter: { tags: arrayOfTags }"` to no avail.

Someone mind pointing me in the right direction? :)

**PS:** I had this working earlier this week by calling a `filterByTag(tag)` function in my controller. This would loop through every task in the array of tasks and if it had the tag that matched, it would hide that task. Similarly **re-activating** a tag would do the same thing, loop through everyone and work the magic... but I'm told that my method was slow + overkill, because "angular filters can handle all of that for you, and it will be more best-practicy". Hence, why I'm here, trying to figure out how to let Angular do the work for me :)

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You could write a custom [filter](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter). The filter would be given the list of active tags, `tags`, and the array of tasks to be filtered, `tasks`, and would output an array of filtered tags. It will be much the same as what you've already done, but with no extra function on the scope.

```
angular.module('myApp').filter('selectedTags', function() {
    return function(tasks, tags) {
        return tasks.filter(function(task) {

            for (var i in task.Tags) {
                if (tags.indexOf(task.Tags[i]) != -1) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;

        });
    };
});
```

Then you can use it like

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="task in tasks | selectedTags:tags"></li>
</ul>
```

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6mqbm/).

Comment: Solid answer covering the concept, however I think to be slightly more accurate to what the question wants it would be rejecting any Tasks containing a tag in a list of tags that are not selected in the interface. As opposed to accepting Tasks containing a tag in a list of tags that are selected in the interface.

Comment: @Rich I'm not completely sure what you mean. Do you mean the "list of tags" should be of rejected/deactivated tags, rather than accepted/activated tags?

Comment: Yea, that's what it seemed like the question is asking for. Quoting 'I need to be able to click on one of those buttons to "toggle off" that tag -- which will filter out any tasks rows in the table wherein the task has that tag.'

Comment: I see your point, but I think the question is ambiguous to this point. 'All the buttons are blue by default, meaning "active" (in other words: show tasks with this tag contained therein).' Whether a task needs to have all its tags activated to be shown is not clear, if I'm not missing anything?

Comment: I think you are right. Rereading it, the language in the question is contradictory to itself so either interpretation is possible. 'Like so for visual reference -- grey = "hide tasks whose tags contains this tag", blue = "show tasks whose tags contain this tag":' In fact the interpretation you have is more common sense anyway.

Comment: Yeah sorry guys the wording is a bit confusing. "Whether a task needs to have all its tags activated to be shown is not clear, if I'm not missing anything?" -- that's a good point that I hadn't considered. I think the way it's actually meant (gotta talk to my boss about it) is essentially: blue = do nothing.... grey = hide tasks that contain this tag, simple as that.

Comment: @user2275203 Obtaining this functionality is as simple as swapping `return false;` and `return true;`. If the answer solves your problem, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: You are a lifesaver! I adapted this example to use Resources and Keyword instead of Tasks and Tags respectively and it worked a treat. The only difference is that when no tags are selected I want all resources to be displayed, so I have a conditional that says `if (keywords.length > 0) { /* do the filtering */ } else {return true;}`