# Angularjs Filter by an Array of values

Tags: angularjs, filter

i've checqued this : 
[AngularJS filter based on array of strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22024631/angularjs-filter-based-on-array-of-strings)

But i've still got difficulties to know how to do :

My data model is this, they are footballers :

```
$scope.footballers = [
        {'identifiant':1,'prenom':'Jean','nom':'Valjean','categorie':1,'ville':'Détroit','age':12,'date_embauche':'','salaire':25,'photo':'1.jpg','vitesse':55,'agilite':3,'deduction':25,'choisi':false},
        {'identifiant':2,'prenom':'Aziz','nom':'Jojo','categorie':2,'ville':'Paris','age':14,'date_embauche':'','salaire':25,'vitesse':57,'agilite':31,'deduction':25,'choisi':false},
        {'identifiant':3,'prenom':'Thierry','nom':'Goubert','categorie':1,'ville':'Paris','age':17,'date_embauche':'','salaire':28,'photo':'2.jpg','vitesse':45,'agilite':3,'deduction':2,'choisi':false},
        {'identifiant':4,'prenom':'Roland','nom':'Grondin','categorie':2,'ville':'Paris','age':14,'date_embauche':'','salaire':25,'vitesse':5,'agilite':34,'deduction':2,'choisi':false},
        {'identifiant':5,'prenom':'Gogok','nom':'Rodolphe','categorie':1,'ville':'Paris','age':17,'date_embauche':'','salaire':28,'photo':'3.jpg','vitesse':68,'agilite':75,'deduction':2,'choisi':false},
        {'identifiant':6,'prenom':'Thierry','nom':'Chalamerto','categorie':1,'ville':'Paris','age':17,'date_embauche':'','salaire':28,'vitesse':55,'agilite':57,'deduction':75,'choisi':false},
        {'identifiant':7,'prenom':'Gawivk','nom':'Gonzogues','categorie':2,'ville':'Paris','age':14,'date_embauche':'','salaire':25,'vitesse':10,'agilite':44,'deduction':2,'choisi':false},
        {'identifiant':8,'prenom':'Thomas','nom':'Choubal','categorie':1,'ville':'Paris','age':12,'date_embauche':'','salaire':28,'vitesse':5,'agilite':3,'deduction':2,'choisi':false}
    ];
```

Now, I would like to display only the footballer who has the identifiant 2,3 and 8 for example.

Let's say I 've got this array :

```
var iwanttofilter = [2,3,8];
```

How could i do to filter with angularJs, firstly, in my ng-repeat, and secondly directly into my controller ?

Thank you.

Comment: You'll want to use an AngularJS filter: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Comment: there is no example of filtering with an arrays of values

Answer (score 2):

In pure angular way

```
var filteredList = $filter('filter')($scope.footballers, function (i) {
  return (i.identifiant === 2 || i.identifiant === 3 || i.identifiant === 8);
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, let's try this!

Comment: This is Exactly what i need, except that it doesn't pick values from the iwanttofilter array. how could i add a angular.foreach or a for loop inside the function to iterate over the iwanttofilter array ?

Answer (score 1):

you can create a custom filter like this

```
 .filter('cust',function(){
      var iwanttofilter = [2,3,8];
      return function(item){ 
         return item.filter(o=>iwanttofilter.find(k=> o.identifiant == k))        
      }
 })
```

in here array will filter according the `iwanttofilter` array and return the result

Demo

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){

$scope.footballers = [
        {'identifiant':1,'prenom':'Jean','nom':'Valjean','categorie':1,'ville':'Détroit','age':12,'date_embauche':'','salaire':25,'photo':'1.jpg','vitesse':55,'agilite':3,'deduction':25,'choisi':false},
        {'identifiant':2,'prenom':'Aziz','nom':'Jojo','categorie':2,'ville':'Paris','age':14,'date_embauche':'','salaire':25,'vitesse':57,'agilite':31,'deduction':25,'choisi':false},
        {'identifiant':3,'prenom':'Thierry','nom':'Goubert','categorie':1,'ville':'Paris','age':17,'date_embauche':'','salaire':28,'photo':'2.jpg','vitesse':45,'agilite':3,'deduction':2,'choisi':false},
        {'identifiant':4,'prenom':'Roland','nom':'Grondin','categorie':2,'ville':'Paris','age':14,'date_embauche':'','salaire':25,'vitesse':5,'agilite':34,'deduction':2,'choisi':false},
        {'identifiant':5,'prenom':'Gogok','nom':'Rodolphe','categorie':1,'ville':'Paris','age':17,'date_embauche':'','salaire':28,'photo':'3.jpg','vitesse':68,'agilite':75,'deduction':2,'choisi':false},
        {'identifiant':6,'prenom':'Thierry','nom':'Chalamerto','categorie':1,'ville':'Paris','age':17,'date_embauche':'','salaire':28,'vitesse':55,'agilite':57,'deduction':75,'choisi':false},
        {'identifiant':7,'prenom':'Gawivk','nom':'Gonzogues','categorie':2,'ville':'Paris','age':14,'date_embauche':'','salaire':25,'vitesse':10,'agilite':44,'deduction':2,'choisi':false},
        {'identifiant':8,'prenom':'Thomas','nom':'Choubal','categorie':1,'ville':'Paris','age':12,'date_embauche':'','salaire':28,'vitesse':5,'agilite':3,'deduction':2,'choisi':false}
    ];
    
    var iwanttofilter = [2,3,8];
    $scope.cust = function(){
      return function(item){
        return iwanttofilter.find(k=> item.identifiant == k)
      }
    }
    
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
 <div ng-repeat="item in footballers | filter:cust() track by $index ">{{item.identifiant}} </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But the iwanttofilter array is inside the controller, not inside the filter, i dont know what to do. the iwanttofilter array values might change anytime.

Answer (score 0):

You pass the `iwanttofilter` into the filter, and filter your list based on each item.

```
MyApp.filter("fewerFootballers", [
    function() {
        return function(footballers, iwanttofilter) {
            return arrayIntersection(footballers, iwanttofilter);

            function arrayIntersection(a, b) {
                return a.filter(function(x) {
                    return b.indexOf(x.identifiant) != -1;
                });
            }
        }
    }]);
```

In your html you use the filter.

```
{{ $scope.footballers | fewerFootballers: $scope.iwanttofilter }}
```

Comment: Ok let's try this

Comment: Did you have any luck?

Comment: Yes it is working thank you a lot, but i've had to use the filter directly inside a function ... See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43353644/return-0-to-n-arrays-values-inside-a-function