# Return 0 to n arrays values inside a function

Tags: angularjs, for-loop, filter

I've got a really complex problem.

I've got this dynamic array , that might include 0 to -> n values :

This is an example :

```
var array =[2,3,8];
```

this is the second example :

```
var array =[2,3,8,15,25];
```

Now, i need to execute this function( gently given by a stakoverflower), but i don't know how to consider each values each times; it is a static function for now, that is working well :

```
var filteredList = $filter('filter')($scope.footballers, function (i) {
      return (i.identifiant === 2 || i.identifiant === 3 || i.identifiant === 8);
 });
```

But look, it works for the first array example, but not for the second array example.

If i want to treat the second array, i need to type this :

```
 var filteredList = $filter('filter')($scope.footballers, function (i) {
      return (i.identifiant === 2 || i.identifiant === 3 || i.identifiant === 8 || i.identifiant === 15 || i.identifiant === 25);
 });
```

My question is : How could i add a for loop inside the $filter function, to be able to treat the second array or whatever long the array is ?

Thank you a lot if you have an idea. The loop would then automatically type i.identifiant === array[0], i.identifiant === array[1] and so on !

I've never encoutered this case, and i really don't know how to return a dynamic long array !

This would also work for the first example :

```
    var filteredList = $filter('filter')($scope.footballers, function (i) {
      return (i.identifiant === array[0] || i.identifiant === array[1] || i.identifiant === array[2]);
 });
```

But how could i do if my array contains 12 values ??? I need a loop, but i dont know how to do at all !

The loop would then be supposed to type "i.identifiant === array[x]"

Ooops , i forgot, my goal is to display a list of footballers whoses identifiers are presents inside the array "array", using angularjs. Into a drag and drop application.  That is why i filter, there are a large amount of identifiers inside $scope.footballers, but i only wanna keep a few, the ones presents inside the array ! The problem is that the array "array" may contain 2 values as well as 25 values .

I was thinking about a loop with an eval() inside or at the end?

Comment: Arrays have an indexOf() method. You want to verify if your array contains the ID of the footballer. Use indexOf(). And while you're at it, read the documentation of the other array methods. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: Thank you, but i need to return something with exactly this syntaxe :  return (i.identifiant === array[0] || i.identifiant === array[1] || i.identifiant === array[2]);

Comment: No, you don't. You need to do `return array.indexOf(i.identifiant) >= 0`. Why do you ask a question if you reject the answer?

Comment: Your question doesn't make a lot of sense. You show an array of numbers, but they you show a filter which acts on an array of objects.

Comment: It maybe doesnt make sense, but it is working. The goal is to display footballers whose identifiers are presents inside the array.

Comment: @nick, hence the use a a function which allows checking if something is present in an array: array.indexOf().

Comment: Is this one the real context where the problem needs to be solved?? If it's this one, the comment made by @JBNizet can be considered as a valid answer, otherwise, you should expose what the real context is.

Comment: It is not >= 0 it can be 2, 15 , 25 , 42 . I need to return this with this syntax i.identifiant === array[0] || i.identifiant === array[1] ||... ->n. I do not need to find the index of the array, i need to return each values of the array , for $filter to work.

Comment: Do i have to use indexOf() on $scope.footballers ? It is probably what you mean.

Comment: No, you don't. What I mean is exactly what I wrote above: `return array.indexOf(i.identifiant) >= 0`: it checks if your array (for example [2,3,8,15,25]) contains the ID of the footballer. So it does exactly the same thing as `return (i.identifiant === 2 || i.identifiant === 3 || i.identifiant === 8 || i.identifiant === 15 || i.identifiant === 25)`.

Comment: Oh yes it is working, thank you a lot ! I'm not able yet to understand how, but congrats you're so good ! dont know if i ll be able to understand one day, its hard for me!

Comment: I know you will maybe hate me, but how would i do the contrario than return array.indexOf(i.identifiant) >= 0 ? I need to show identifiers that Aren't included to array (It is the contrario) Iv'e tried : return array.indexOf(i.identifiant) >!= 0  with no luck

Comment: I mean the inverse sorry

Comment: Solved my problem with this : return presence_equipe.indexOf(i.identifiant) === -1 thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok JB Nizet gave me the answer, thank you a lot, it's above my level, but it is working, so nice !.

If u're curious about my labo, it's here :

http://nicolash.org/football/#/liste

have a nice day

Solved the inverse problem with this : 
[Is it possible to filter angular.js by containment in another array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15454900/is-it-possible-to-filter-angular-js-by-containment-in-another-array)

And finally got that inverse function :

```
$scope.footballers = $filter('filter')($scope.footballers, function (i) {
       return presence_equipe.indexOf(i.identifiant) === -1
});
```

thanks a lot !!

Comment: I know you will maybe hate me, but how would i do the contrario than return array.indexOf(i.identifiant) >= 0 ? I need to show identifiers that Aren't included to array (It is the contrario) Iv'e tried : return array.indexOf(i.identifiant) >!= 0 with no luck

Comment: Solved my problem with this : return presence_equipe.indexOf(i.identifiant) === -1 thanks a lot !!