# How can I filter items in ngRepeat from array of numbers?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I'm struggling to find a way of filtering a set of results in an ng-repeat, based on an array of numbers.  The numbers can represent results I want to see, or not see.  I'm able to use a filter in the view and filter by one number, which works, but I want to put an array there and filter by the array.  I don't care if the filter is in the view, the controller, or a separate filter.

The code below successfully filters topics with the forum id of 60

```
  <div ng-repeat="topic in topics | filter:{forum_id:60}">
    Forum ID: {{topic.forum_id}} Forum Name: {{topic.forum_title}}
  </div>
```

I want to filter by an array

```
  <div ng-repeat="topic in topics | filter:{forum_id:ARRAY_HERE}">
    Forum ID: {{topic.forum_id}} Forum Name: {{topic.forum_title}}
  </div>
```

Full plunk here:
https://plnkr.co/edit/dCZ7DV?p=preview

Comment: Please include all relevant code in a [mcve] in the question itself. Don't just post a link to the code that shows the issue, as many people are behind firewalls that disallow navigation to code sharing sites. You can replicate a lot of web functionality using Stack Snippets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass your own function to filter:

```
<div ng-repeat="topic in topics | filter:myFilterMethod(topic)">
    Forum ID: {{topic.forum_id}} Forum Name: {{topic.forum_title}}
</div>
```

and in your controller:

```
$scope.myFilterMethod = function() {
    return function(e) {
        return $scope.filterBy.includes(e.forum_id);
    }
}
```

[updated plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/EZSgir?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use `ng-if` and `indexOf` function for this.

```
 <div ng-repeat="topic in topics" ng-if="filterBy.indexOf(topic.forum_id) !== -1">
     Forum ID: {{topic.forum_id}} Forum Name: {{topic.forum_title}}
 </div>
```

[**Demo**](https://plnkr.co/edit/zTYwiLyBJKn84IwdJkQ0?p=preview)

Comment: Hadi and baao's examples both work great. Which one would be best from a performance standpoint?

Comment: I think @baao answer is best.

Answer (score 1):

natively, the filter property in angular doesn't work that way, so you need to define a manual filter by yourself.

You can do it like this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22024631/angularjs-filter-based-on-array-of-strings)

```
angular.module('myApp').filter('selectedArray', function() {
    return function(array, tags) {
        return array.filter(function(object) {

            for (var i in object.XXX) {
                if (array.indexOf(object.XXX[i]) != -1) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;

        });
    };
});
```

and then you can use it like :

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="task in tasks | selectedArray:Array"></li>
</ul>
```

In this example as the response is a array of objects, you need to tailor it to your array,

Hope it helps.